# How to create a function with a for loop to obtain multiple pdf files (unique per id) with ggplots on spearate pages

Tags: r, c, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to create pdf report file using a function and a for loop, but I would like to have 1 ggplot per page in my file. I create this function and for loop to be able to have 1 report per name because it needs to be individualized. So far my code looks like this

```
tv<- data.frame(
  name = c("p1","p2","p3","p1","p2","p3","p1","p2","p3","p1","p2","p3", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p1", "p2", "p3"),
  dates = c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010","2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015" ),
  results = c(40, 40, 45, 50, 52, 52, 53, 54, 56, 70, 50, 10, 40, 55, 55, 60, 60, 70, 30, 60, 60, 55, 55, 54, 32, 33, 57),
  parameter = c("D", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R", "C", "C", "C","D", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R", "C", "C", "C")
)


ftv <- function(id){
  Ttv <- tv %>% filter(name == id)
  ggplot(Ttv, aes(dates, results, group = parameter)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90), strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    facet_wrap(~parameter, scales = "free")+
  ggsave(paste0("~/Desktop//", id, "_test.pdf"))
}

for(id in unique(tv$name)){
  ftv(id)
}
```

And I obtain this

[image]

I would like to have the same type of file, but each page containing 1 plot, considering that later on I might want to have more than 3 graph in the file.

thank you for you help.

Comment: So you want each facet in one different page or all the plots regardless id in different pages?

Comment: @Duck I want each facet in one different page. Each id should create their own pdf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Function
ftv <- function(id){
  Ttv <- tv %>% filter(name == id)
  LTtv <- split(Ttv,Ttv$parameter)
  Lplot <- lapply(LTtv, function(x) 
    ggplot(x, aes(dates, results, group = parameter)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90), strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    facet_wrap(~parameter, scales = "free"))
  #Export
  pdf(paste0(id,'.pdf'),width = 14)
  lapply(Lplot,plot)
  dev.off()
}
#Apply
for(id in unique(tv$name)){
  ftv(id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
# create a new variable that combines the two variables for identifying cases    
tv$name_parameter<-paste0(tv$name,tv$parameter)


ftv <- function(id){

Ttv <- tv %>% filter(name_parameter == id) # use the new identifier here
ggplot(Ttv, aes(dates, results, group = parameter)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90), strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
# # remove facet_wrap bc you're using `parameter` to paginate   
# facet_wrap(~parameter, scales = "free")+   
ggsave(paste0("~/Desktop//", id, "_test.pdf"))
 }


for(id in unique(tv$name_parameter)){  # again, the new identifier
ftv(id)
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, i would like to be able to create 1 pdf file names, so as an example "p1" as 1 pdf file with 3 page, 1 for each parameter, same for "p2" and "p3"